# Line art modifier cleanup help

Tags: grease-pencil, lineart

I'm running in Blender 3.6, and wanted my line art to show up in the shape of the object only. It's like having all the contours MINUS the silhouettes. For this, I just clicked on invert for individual silhouette. It looks fine for a simple cube I edited to see the effect, but for the monkey there are still little specks on the outline of the object. Is there someway to make it cleaner so I can omit the very short lines?

*I also added a subdivision and thickness modifier below the line art modifier

[image]